# Adding a single column-row field in tikz table

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

How do I add a single row-column tikz table field say in the middle above A2 and A3 which combines both right columns?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shadings,arrows,decorations.markings,decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{
    table/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={
            rectangle,
            draw=black,
            align=center,
                        text width=10em,
                        fill=gray!10,
                   },
                        %baseline={([yshift=-0.5ex]current bounding box.center)},
        %minimum height=1.0em,
        %text depth=0.2em,
        %text height=0.8em,
                %text centered,
        nodes in empty cells,
                row 1/.style={nodes={fill=black, text=white, font=\bfseries}},
                row 2/.style={nodes={text height=3.3ex}},
            }
        }


\begin{document}

Hello World...
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[table, ampersand replacement=\&] (TabA1)
{
A1 \& A2 \& A3 \\
B1 \& $10^{2^{3^{4^{5}}}}$ \& B3 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Glossary}
\label{tabA1}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You've asked 15 questions so far and not accepted any of the answers. May I ask why?

Comment: 15 questions? What do you mean by accept?

Comment: If one looks at [your profile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/107017/diger) one sees that you've asked 15 questions so far. none of their answers is accepted. You can [accept an answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer?s=2|37.5210) to *your* question by clicking on the check mark left of it. In addition you may consider upvoting an answer by clicking on the uparrow left of it.

Comment: Just Like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use fit for that.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shadings,arrows,decorations.markings,decorations.pathmorphing,fit}
\tikzset{
    table/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={
            rectangle,
            draw=black,
            align=center,
                        text width=10em,
                        fill=gray!10,
                   },
                        %baseline={([yshift=-0.5ex]current bounding box.center)},
        %minimum height=1.0em,
        %text depth=0.2em,
        %text height=0.8em,
                %text centered,
        nodes in empty cells,
                row 1/.style={nodes={fill=black, text=white, font=\bfseries}},
                row 2/.style={nodes={text height=3.3ex}},
            }
        }


\begin{document}

Hello World...
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[table, ampersand replacement=\&] (TabA1)
{
A1 \& A2 \& A3 \\
B1 \& $10^{2^{3^{4^{5}}}}$ \& B3 \\
};
\node[fit=(TabA1-1-2) (TabA1-1-3),yshift=16pt,draw,inner sep=-\pgflinewidth/2,
minimum height=24pt]{I fit two nodes};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Glossary}
\label{tabA1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, what is the pgflinewidth/2 for?

Comment: But I'm using pgflinewidth*1 in the definitions. Why now dividing by 2 ? Shouldn't it be 1?

Comment: I know I noticed. I was just saying that I'm surprised because the original definition was *1 and not *1/2

Comment: @Diger Setting `column sep` and `row sep` to `-\pgflinewidth` will just make Ti*k*Z draw the boundaries on top of each other. Setting `inner sep` to `-\pgflinewidth/2` makes sure that the outer edge of the box coincides with the outer ends of the node(s) that it fits.

Comment: So setting `column sep` and `row sep` e.g. to 2 separates the boundaries by how much `pt`?

Comment: Right. This is negative `-2*\pgflinewidth` and will not cause gaps, but what if `+2*\pgflinewidth` ? Will the lines be `2pt` apart?

Comment: Trying out would not tell me the gap size i.e. a number. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Diger Sorry, most likely I simply do not understand your questions. The distance is measured between the centers of the (bounding) lines. So if you set the distance to `x` then the outer edges of those lines will be apart by `x-2*\pgflinewidth/2=x-\pgflinewidth`.

Comment: Yes thanks, but is this distance measured in `pt` or what unit?

Comment: @Diger You can always specify the unit.

Comment: and how big is 1*pgflinewidth e.g. in pt?

Comment: @Diger the standard preset value is `0.4pt`, just add `\typeout{\the\pgflinewidth}` inside the tikzpicture in your code